# Typescript - Generic Type Variables: Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T'. Two different types exists with this name exist but they are unrelated

Tags: typescript, generics, contravariance, typescript3.0

Using typescript 3.0+. See the following simple setup involving generic typed variables:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  public abstract merge<T>(model?: T): T;
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {

  public Value: string;

  public merge<MyClass>(model?: MyClass): MyClass {
    this.Value += model.Value; // <--Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'MyClass'

    return this; // <--Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'MyClass'.
                 //    Type 'MyClass' is not assignable to type 'MyClass'.
                 //    Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
  }
}
```

I noted the errors described from the Typescript compiler but these errors don't make sense to me. Why is this wrong?

**UPDATED**

I understand now that the original code above the merge method in MyClass was defining a new generic typed variable with the same name as "MyClass", which explains the error. So I make the change as seen below. This still produces an error, which I commented above the merge method:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  public abstract merge<T>(model?: T): T;
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {

  public Value: string;

/*
Property 'merge' in type 'MyClass' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BaseClass'.
  Type '(model?: MyClass) => MyClass' is not assignable to type '<T>(model?: T) => T'.
    Types of parameters 'model' and 'model' are incompatible.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'MyClass'.
*/
  public merge(model?: MyClass): MyClass {
    this.Value += model.Value;

    return this;
  }
}
```

Why can't I use MyClass as the variable type here? In fact, I can't seem to replace it with any other type that would make it work (e.g. string, number, another class).

Even if I try to define T as a type that extends BaseClass:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  public abstract merge<T extends BaseClass>(model?: T): T;
}
```

This still generates the same error in MyClass. Note that this works fine with TypeScript 2.2.1. I only noticed this not working with any TypeScript version 2.4+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<MyClass>` in `public merge<MyClass>` introduces another type (generic), which is different from the `class MyClass`, but has the same name. Nothing is known about this generic type, therefore you get the error `Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'MyClass'`.

The `this` of type `class MyClass`, the `model` is of the generic type.

If your base class defines the method as `merge<T>(model?: T): T`, the derived class needs to use the same definition. You promised in your base class you will process any parameter (generic T without any restrictions), you cannot restrict it only to `MyClass` in a derived class.

Comment: If I made the change you suggested, then I get a different error:

`Property 'merge' in type 'MyClass' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BaseClass'.
  Type '(model?: MyClass) => MyClass' is not assignable to type '<T>(model?: T) => T'.
    Types of parameters 'model' and 'model' are incompatible.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'MyClass'.`

Comment: I missed the T part of the question. I will try to update the answer.

Comment: If the derived class needs to also use a generic variable type, then how can I use a strongly type parameter and return value? This doesn't seem useful or right.

The only way I was able to make this work is to move the generic variable type up to the class level in the BaseClass. But it seems very odd to say:
`class MyClass extends BaseClass<MyClass> {...`

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve. Perhaps you base / derived hierarchy design is wrong? Once you promise in the BaseClass you are able to merge with any model, you cannot take the promise back in the MyClass and say you are able to merge with MyClass only.

Comment: I want to make the merge method strongly type with a type defined by the derived class. This type will be different depending on the class inheriting BaseClass. Using TypeScript 2.2, this was working fine, but with TypeScript 2.5+ I get these errors. It really seems like a bug with TypeScript, but I think I found a workaround. I'll post it as an answer once ready.

Comment: I updated my question again showing that I still get an error if I define T as a type that extends BaseClass. It is also worth noting that this worked fine with TypeScript 2.2.1.

Comment: What you want is contrary to what is possible. What should happen if someone holds a variable with type known as BaseClass, and using this variable attempts to merge with a model which is not MyClass? This language independent reason why parameters need to be contravariant - derived class can never restrict the parameters compared to the base class, as the method may be called using the interface of the base class.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thank you for your help on this!